# Typical burner/combustor dimensions of a jet engine

Tags: engine, jet

I know that sounds very generic but lets say for a common engine of a passenger airplane. What could be the typical dimensions for the burner part. I can't find anything online.

Thanks.

Comment: Go checkout your local aviation museum?

Comment: What if there isnt a local aviation museum?

Comment: 30-40% the diameter of the first compressor stage is a good estimation for a normal combustor.